# WSO2 API Manager(wso2am-4.1.0) - Exposing APIs Using a Virtual Host

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using wso2am-4.1.0 and I'm trying to expose APIs using a custom vhost and I followed "Using an existing Gateway environment to expose APIs via custom hostnames" section of the following documentation.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/deploy-api/exposing-apis-via-custom-hostnames/

However, this does not seem to be working since the vhost is not visible in the API deployment phase even after adding the relevant configurations in the deployment.toml.

A resolution for this is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you observing any errors during the WSO2 API Manager startup? Furthermore, please do check the deployment.toml configurations in the running instance of the WSO2 API Manager to confirm that the expected configurations are present.

Comment: Hi @Athiththan I was able to get the vhosts displayed at the API deployment stage. However, a "connection refused" error occurs when I try to access the API using a vhost with port 443. For testing, I deployed the API using us.wso2.com as per the documentation but I cannot invoke the API due to the said error.